# Bad Request - Invalid Hostname when accessing with other than localhost:port

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express

When I use `localhost:1766` to access my asp.net application, I can access my application successfully.

Unfortunately it isn't working using this IP/Port: `192.168.178.100:1766`

The browser gives me the following output:

> Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
>
> HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.

The IP is my local ip address I retrieved from `ipconfig /all`
Further more I checked my `applicationhost.config`, but I can't find anything in there, when I am searching for 1766 or someithing similar.

Does Visual Studio use another config? What can I do to access my application with the given ip / port?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you check your hostname configuration of your system.

Comment: What should i check?

Comment: you can get some help here http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-hosts-file/

Comment: @mohitkumar that's not related at all.

Comment: Our free VS extension 'Conveyor' would help, it opens up IIS Express without config changes https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti

Answer (score 0):

The config is elsewhere for VS2015:
C:\Users{username}\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects{projectname}.vs\config

Also if you're running your backend project from two different solutions (one with the client and one for the backend alone), then be careful there are two files so modify the one you actually run.